# ssh sshd config % param substring

Tags: linux, ssh, configuration

As of right now I have a configuration section on my sshd config like so

```
Match Group purecore
  ChrootDirectory /etc/purecore/hosted/%u
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Where %u is the username of the user logging in. In my users setup, I always create users with the usernames beginning with 'u' (in order to prevent usernames to start with a number). Since all the users start with 'u', I would love the user 'uxxx' to have its chroot directory to **/etc/purecore/hosted/xxx**, instead of **/etc/purecore/hosted/uxxx**. Is there any possible way to create a substring of %u in the sshd_config itself, removing the first character? Or taking last x characters?

Note this is purely for aesthetic purposes in my filesystem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/etc/purecore/hosted/xxx` is the home directory for user, you can use `%h`, which points to the home directory of the user. More information here: https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#TOKENS